# C++ doubly linked list search

Tags: c++, search, doubly-linked-list

I have a doubly linked list like a drum that contains all the alphabets in it (small and caps) and i have to find the shortest path between two alphabets, but i can't think of algorithm for it how to find it, and when i find it how to continue the new search from the new alpha?

The code i done so far is creating the list and printing the alphabets that are in the word.

```
static void CreateAlph(drum* &Head){
drum* Last=Head;
drum* P;

for (int i = 0; i < 58; i++)
{
    if (i<26 || i>31)
    {
        P=new drum;
        P->alpha=65+i;
        P->next=Head;
        if (Head==NULL)
        {
            Head = P;
            P->prev=NULL;
        }else
        {
            P->prev=Last;
            Last->next=P;
        }
        Last=P;
    }

}
```

and for the printing i use do while because i don't have in the end NULL

```
if (head) {
    do
    {
        for (int i =0; i<58; i++) {
            if (word[i]==P->alpha) {
                cout<<"-> "<<P->alpha<<endl;
            }
        }
        P=P->next;
    }while (P!=head);
}
```

But i can't think of algorithm for finding the shortest path.

Comment: Start by naming your variables correctly. The names you are using are awful and lead to detorientation.

Comment: To accomplish this you actually need no linked list. You can simply calculate the distance since the list is stored in an ordered way.

Comment: This is a task from class it has to be linked.